# Prolog - Return the n-th column of a matrix

Tags: matrix, prolog, logic

I am trying to write the predicate `columnN/3` which returns the "nth" element of a matrix.

Example:

```
columnN([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], 1, CJ). 
CJ = [1,3,5];
No
```

With the help of the community, I was able to try to use the predicate `rowN/3` in order to try to get the columns.

This is what I have so far:

```
rowN([H|_],1,H):-!.
rowN([_|T],I,X) :-
    I1 is I-1,
    rowN(T,I1,X).

columnN([],[],[]).
columnN([H|T], I, [R|X]):-
   rowN(H, I, R), 
columnN(T,I,X).
```

I just get false. 
The `rowN/3` predicate works pretty fine, `rowI([1,2,3,4], 2, RI).` will return `2`, so I was thinking using this, I could enter each row, get the value and append it to a list. (Which I tried to do with the `columnN` predicate).

How is my code wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your base case for `columnN` is `columnN([], [], [])`. Your second argument is an empty list. But your predicate is defined to have an integer (column number) for second argument. So this base case will always fail.

Comment: Wow it was just that!!!!! Thank you!!! I changed it to:
`columnN([],_,[]).` instead, and it works.

Comment: @lurker would maplist also be a good idea ?   `columnN(X,Y,Z):-
           maplist(rowN, X, Y, Z).`

Comment: @krishnakalyan that's the short solution, but that doesn't answer the OP's question, nor does the OP have a `list_head_tail` predicate defined.

Comment: @lurker just made an edit

Comment: @KrishnaKalyan yes, this sort of problem would be ideal for `maplist`. :)

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could help me with a solution with maplist. The code i have posted above is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment above from @lurker, this code works:

```
rowN([H|_],1,H):-!.
rowN([_|T],I,X) :-
    I1 is I-1,
    rowN(T,I1,X).

columnN([],_,[]).
columnN([H|T], I, [R|X]):-
   rowN(H, I, R), 
columnN(T,I,X).
```

Comment: You are also allowed to accept your own answer in SO, if you wish. :)